# offset() values after replacing html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, offset

I have a div acting as a wrapper that contains almost the whole DOM (From body to /body) of a website. If I get the `offset()` of one of the elements when document is ready everything is ok but after a replacement `$('#wrapper').html(newContent)` the offset is **0**.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

If `#wrapper` is your content wrapper, then you're essentially swapping out your whole content with a new DOM subtree. That means that any element that was inside your `#wrapper` is now not part of the DOM anymore. The following code illustrates your problem:

```
$.ready(function() {
  var elem = $('#somediv'),
      wrapper = $('#wrapper'),
      newContent = '<div>...</div>';

  alert(elem.offset().top); // displays the correct offset

  wrapper.html(newContent); // swaps out the contents of #wrapper, destroys #somediv

  alert(elem.offset().top); // displays 0, because `elem` is not inside #wrapper anymore
});
```

A working example can be seen here: [snippet@jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krofdrakula/UrpGg/)

Comment: Thanks Krof for your help. Is there anyway to recover DOM control?

Comment: Sorry, I'm reading again your answer and I found that there have been some missunderstanding. After replacement, I'm asking for the offset() of an element that was there before and is there again. This replacement is in fact only adding more stuff in different places but it keeps the old elemnts as well.

Comment: I understand what you're saying – but when you use `.html(...)` on an element, all the content of that element gets recreated. The old elements do not exist anymore, even if the classes and IDs are the same. If you want to see what the offset for the new element is, reselect the element you want to inspect again using `$(...)` and it will report the correct offset.

Comment: Hello again Krof, I'm reselecting the element again, but it doesn't return it's offset anymore...
An example: 
BEFORE REPLACEMENT:
$('#menu_1').offset().top = 40;
AFTER REPLACEMENT:

Comment: Sorry for the redundancy, but I spent more than 5 minutes:
Hello again Krof, I'm reselecting the element again, but it doesn't return it's offset anymore...
An example: 
BEFORE REPLACEMENT:
$('#menu_1').offset().top = 40;
AFTER REPLACEMENT:
$('#menu_1').offset().top = 0;
This happens even though the element is still there and in the same position, instead, if I write $('#menu_1').offset().top in the firebug console I get the right data...

Comment: Please check the code, it contains the relevant working code. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krofdrakula/UrpGg/)